# How to trigger model save for a computed property in Ember

Tags: ember.js

So I have a `computed.not` property that is the giving me the reverse of a model field. I then have a checkbox in a view that is using the computed property. How do I save the correct value for the model field when the checkbox is checked or unchecked?

See pesudo code

In controller

```
reversedField: Ember.computed.not('field'),
```

view

```
{{input type="checkbox" checked=reversedField }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle setting the computed property by explicitly defining your computed property, which is [described in the guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/#toc_setting-computed-properties).

In your specific example, the computed property would look like this:

```
  reversedField: function(key, value) {
    // setter
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
      console.log(value);
      this.set('field', !value);
    }

    // getter
    return !this.get('field');
  }.property('field')
```

[JSBin example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dogem/2/edit)